# How can I output the result of a PL/SQL script to a grid?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to figure out how I can output the results of a PL/SQL script to a results grid the same way results from a simple query are output. I'm new to Oracle from SQL Server, so I might be overlooking something very basic. For example how would I view the results of something like the following simple T-SQL (SQL Server's PL) script? Is there some sort of print_to_grid function? Or perhaps using a cursor? I know about dbms_output, but I definitely don't want to have to concatenate a string out of every script I want to see results from.

```
declare @emps table(employeeId int, name varchar(40)

insert into @emps
select employeeID, name
from employees

select * from @emps
```

This seems like it should be the simplest thing in the world, but I can't find a straight answer for it. Any help or tool recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you wanting to use a grid feature once it's there - like a sort, single record view, export, etc?

Comment: also, you don't need a pl/sql script to run SQL - why not just have the SQL Statement by itself?

Comment: You can't use a SELECT statement without an INTO clause within a procedural block (either anonymous or stored).

Comment: one final comment - if you are going to run SQL in pl/sql like that - you need to select the results into a PL/SQL object - you would need to declare a cursor to be used to manipulate the results with your code - if you just want to run the sql, do it outside of plsql

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, I don't need any features other than being able to view the results. The point of the script is just to be able to use more than one statement, such as the above example where I first declare a variable and then use it in a query. Obviously with the above example it would be easier to cut out the variable and just stick the value directly in the select statement, but I want this functionality for working with more complicated scripts and queries.

Comment: @thatJeffSmith, I was trying to use a refcursor to collect the results of the query, but then I don't know how to output the data in the cursor. Like is there some sort of printCursor() function?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Can SQL Dev handle the Oracle 12c DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT output by putting the results in a data grid instead of displaying it textually?  This might satisfy the OPs request.

Comment: @StevenEdmunds please see https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/sqlplus-101-substitution-variables

Comment: @thatJeffSmith, I mean to be asking about multiple statement scripts in general, not about the specific problem of defining a variable. Like for another example, a series of queries that each depended on the results of the query before it. Also, does the link you posted only apply to the SQL Plus command line? I don't want to have to use a command line tool.

Comment: you can run as many sql statements as you want, as simple or complex as you want - SQL Developer execute (F5) supports the SQL*Plus stuff, no CLI necessary

Comment: You are overlooking something basic. PL/SQL is a programming language, not a query language. You use it to either create procedures (code to perform one or more operations) or create functions (code to return a value or object). SQL is used to return rows and columns. If you need to provide the query with an initial value, use a bind variable. @thatjeffsmith is leading you down the correct path with his clarifying questions.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, I really appreciate your help, but bind variables don't really get at the problem. I changed my example to a T-SQL script so it wouldn't look like I was just asking about simple variables. Is there any way with an Oracle database and any client program to get an equivalent script to my new example to output, and without simply combining the two queries into one query. Also, even when using the bind variables with a simple query in SQL Developer, the output is done in messy word wrapped text rather than the normal grid.

Comment: @SamM, thanks, but I don't think bind variables cover all of the things that can be done in a script, like defining collection types. I changed my example to an example in T-SQL so that it wouldn't look like I was just asking about variables. I understand that PL/SQL is a programming language, and maybe Oracle doesn't have anything that is the equivalent to T-SQL which is also a programming language but can still output results in any SQL editor client.

Comment: @StevenEdmunds yeah, you need a cursor https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/working-with-cursors - but what are you going to do with it once you've got the data? if you're just printing the output, you don't need PL/SQL

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, can you do a query on a refcursor?

Comment: SQLDev supports the print command - but are you doing this just to prevent a lock on the table for a query? Bc, Oracle doesn't have that problem

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are after a ref cursor.  For example

```
SQL> variable r refcursor
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    open :r for
  3    select empno, ename
  4    from scott.emp;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> print r

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH
      7499 ALLEN
      7521 WARD
      7566 JONES
      7654 MARTIN
      7698 BLAKE
      7782 CLARK
      7788 SCOTT
      7839 KING
      7844 TURNER
      7876 ADAMS
      7900 JAMES
      7902 FORD
      7934 MILLER

14 rows selected.
```

At the point you open that refcursor, the result is pre-ordained - so there is no need to worry about read locks or data consistency etc.  For example, I'll open the ref cursor when there is rows in the table, and then delete them...my printed data is still as it was at cursor open time.

```
SQL>
SQL>
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    open :r for
  3    select empno, ename
  4    from scott.emp;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> delete from scott.emp;

14 rows deleted.

SQL>
SQL> print r

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH
      7499 ALLEN
      7521 WARD
      7566 JONES
      7654 MARTIN
      7698 BLAKE
      7782 CLARK
      7788 SCOTT
      7839 KING
      7844 TURNER
      7876 ADAMS
      7900 JAMES
      7902 FORD
      7934 MILLER

14 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL>
```

Comment: I've used refcursors, but how do you query one of them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  In Oracle, if you want to see the output from a query, you just run it in the tool of your choice.  It won't take any locks, won't have any consistency/dirty read issues - it just works.  If you are running that query in a PLSQL block and you want to see the output, you'd use a ref cursor like the example above.  The "print" command is owned by the *tool* you are using.  ie, in SQL Plus (like I was using, it's print).  Other tools (SQL Dev etc) have other mechanisms to print out the content of the ref cursor

Comment: In the T-SQL example I gave in the post, the second query queries the results of the first query. Really though I'm trying to figure out how to get output from a script of any number of procedural steps. Obviously, in many cases, as with the example I gave, multiple statements can be easily combined into a single statement, but for longer, more complicated scripts, or pre-existing procedures that I want to examine without changing the procedure. This might just be something that Oracle doesn't have, and that I just took for granted coming from SQL Server.